# Select Options Webdynpro abap no contain CP pattern

Tags: abap, webdynpro, sap-selection-screens

I have got the following issue.

I have implemented `WDR_SELECT_OPTIONS` and it works fine, but i need the `CP`(*) for searching data.

[image]

Someone know why is not there?

Comment: It is not there, because it does not need to be there. If you use a pattern in your field, then the system knows automatically that this is `CP`. Is the `CP` an option in the traditional Dynpro?

Answer (score 1):

CP isn't showing up because it is only available for character-like data elements (things like C, N, or string).

My guess is that field is an integer.

manual page for these relational operators - 
https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenlogexp_op.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is not there, because it does not need to be there. If you type `*` or `+` in this field, then the system knows automatically that this is a pattern.

Here is a screenshot for selection options from a traditional Dynpro.

[image: Selection options]

Comment: If i type (15*) dont recognize CP  pattern.
i debugged and appears  ( sign = i . option= eq, low= 15*).